# Why am I getting a merge error when trying to pull from my repository?

Tags: git

I have a git question about doing a git pull and it says

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
by merge:  
         testFile.java 

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. Aborting
```

If I just want overwrite this one file with the new file in the repository already how do I do it?

Can I fetch somehow and overwrite my local file?

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        schemas/rjtsml.xsd
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Answer (score 4):

`git checkout -- testFile.java` will overwrite local file with the one in the repo. `git checkout --help` if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

As [mardavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982542/mardavi) already mentioned on his answer, if you want to overwrite the local file with the version of the remote, you can do a simple `git checkout -- testFile.java`. **However**, this will only update the file with the version from the remote that your `.git` folder has information about. Since you've mentioned that you tried to do a `git pull`, I'm assuming you want to update your local repository with a remote that *might* have been updated. If this is the case, you should do the following:

Overwrite the testFile.java file with the version that your `.git` folder has information about:

```
git checkout -- testFile.java
```

Fetch data from the remote repository to update your database and merge it with your local branch. This is actually a description of the *git-pull* command. So you simply execute:

```
git pull
```

And now your local branch should be up to date and the *testFile.java* has the newest changes from the remote server.

I recommend the following reading: [Git Branching - Remote Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)